# Desplegable no muestra la opción por defecto seleccionada

Tags: html, django

Tengo un desplegable y no me muestra la opción predeterminada ni seleccionada. Me he basado en páginas de ejemplo como [esta](https://www.hazunaweb.com/curso-de-html/formularios-iii-listas-opciones/) o [esta](https://blog.michelletorres.mx/listas-desplegables-en-los-formularios-html/) y a ellos cuando está plegado les muestra su primera opción.

No entiendo porque pasa, ¿puede ser porque yo paso de manera dinámica con `django` las opciones del desplegable?

Me gustaría que se mostrase la opción seleccionada para luego con ´jquery´ poder trabajarla.

**EDIT** Veo que aquí el snippet si que lo hace, pero cómo muestro en mi imagen no. Solo se ve en el desplegable pero no en el principal(el de arriba)...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

```html
<select>
  {% for node in Last_val_nodes %}
    <option selected class="black_font">{{node.0}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto al aplicar un `select`, estará seleccionado el primer elemento, pero lo estás utilizando de manera equivocada, al poner `node.0` no lo reconoce y por eso sale en blanco.

Lo correcto sería:

```
<select>
  {% for node in Last_val_nodes %}
    <option selected class="black_font">{{node.nombre}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Tomando el atributo que deseas mostrar, en este caso puse `nombre`, podrías incluso no poner el atributo deseado, solo `{{node}}`, siempre y cuando dentro de tu modelo tengas el método `__str__`

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre #O el elemento a mostrar
```

Comment: Pero es que ese 0 es porque viene de una lista y quiero el contenido de la primera posición de esa lista.

Comment: La lista la guardas en un diccionario y la envías al template?

Comment: Si, paso con un diccionario las diferentes variables python a mis templates. Y esta es una lista que contiene en la primera posición un nombre que me interesa

Comment: Cuando pones simplemente {{node}}, que te aparece en el select?

Comment: Toda la lista, algo similar a `['Node_1',39.123,2.123,5,88]`, por eso pongo {{node.0}} para sacar solo el nombre. La cosa es que dentro del desplegable se me genera bien, solo es que sin desplegar no se ve nada. Ahora adjunto otra imagen

Comment: sacando el selected dentro del option sigue igual?

Comment: Si, eso no hace nada para bien ni para mal

Comment: He hecho una lista de los días de la semana y todo, lo he pasado a un template y solo con poner {{node}}, ya me sale pre seleccionado el primero :0

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101617/discussion-between-nea-and-riaven).